# C# - Use a List to create and update the list, which is periodically displayed by the application

Tags: c#, list

This is what I am aiming for:

Class Shirt implements:

-A public enumeration listing the shirt sizes (L, M, S, XL and XXL)

-A constructor which defines three parameters: color, material and size

-Three read-only auto-implemented properties: color, material and size

Application class ShirtDemo:

-Uses the C# generic class List to create and update the list of shirts which is periodically displayed by the application

-Implements one method which defines a parameter of type Shirt. The method is responsible for displaying the details of the shirt (i.e., the actual material, color and size of the shirt)

[image]

This is what I have, but become stuck when it comes to making the List and displaying the output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Cooper_ShirtDemo
{
    public enum Sizes { S, M, L, XL, XXL };
    class Shirt
    {

        public Shirt( string material, string color, Sizes size)
            {
            this.Material = material;
            this.Color = color;
            this.Size = size;
            }

       public Shirt()
        {

        }

        public string Material
        {
            get;
        }

        public string Color
        {
            get; 
        }

        public Sizes Size
        {
            get; 
        }


    }
}

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Cooper_ShirtDemo
    {
        class Program
        {


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*** List Of Shirts ***");
                Console.WriteLine();


            }

            public static void Display(List<string> Shirts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Material        Color      Size");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any issue with your implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a list, declare it as:

```
List<Shirt> shirts = new List<Shirt>();
```

Then add new shirts one at a time:

```
shirts.Add(new Shirt("cotton", "red", Sizes.L));
```

...

You can then display it using a foreach loop:

```
foreach (Shirt s in shirts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Material + "         " + s.Color + "        " + s.Size);
}
```

Comment: ah, I see! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your Shirt class, you can use it to create a list of that type. First you will need some instances of shirt, then you will need to add them to a list of type shirt. Then you are free to iterate the list and write them to the console. This should get you started.

```
class Program
{

    //Create a list of shirts
    static List<Shirt> shirtsList = new List<Shirt>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create some shirts
        Shirt s1 = new Shirt("Cotten", "White", Sizes.L);
        Shirt s2 = new Shirt("Silk", "Blue", Sizes.M);
        Shirt s3 = new Shirt("Poly", "Red", Sizes.S);


        //Add shirts to shirt list 
        shirtsList.Add(s1);
        shirtsList.Add(s2);
        shirtsList.Add(s3);

        Console.WriteLine("*** List Of Shirts ***");
        Display(shirtsList);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void Display(List<Shirt> shirts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Material\tColor\tSize");

        foreach (Shirt s in shirtsList)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t{2}", s.Material, s.Color, s.Size );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think @willie is on the right track.
but....
i would like to suggest using a dictionary. that way you can trace the items in your list.

```
private Dictionary<TKey,TValue> ....= new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>();
```

whit the TKey you can point to the item like in a array.

```
Dictionary<int,Shirt> shirts = new Dictionary<int,shirt>();
```